# How to hide Label in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

i m working on simple asp.net and in that i am using validators.
my situation is like that i have used reaquired field validator its working fine.
and after that if i ented data and fired insert query then data is inserted and sucessful message is displyed on the lable. but agin if i clik on submit button with empty fields then validator works but the lable of successful message does not disapper. how to hide that lable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript to hide the success message, here is a sample

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide() {
    document.getElementById('<%=lblSuccess.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';

    return false;
}
</script>

<asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" Text="Success"></asp:Label>
..your form code
<asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClientClick="hide()" ValidationGroup="ValidateForm" />
```

Why javascript, the form doesn't get posted because validators don't let the form to be posted if the conditions aren't met, so you are left to hide the message dynamically with javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function Hide() {
        document.getElementById("Lable1").style.display = 'none';
        return false;
    }
</script>


<asp:Button ID="Button1"  OnClientClick="Hide()" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"/>
```

and use

```
   if (Page.IsValid){}
```

on clik event.

Answer (score 0):

Show us some code of what you're up to and we can tell you more precisely where you are going wrong. In a nutshell though the visibility of that message is going to be persisted through a postback so you have to explicitly tell it to not be visible if validation has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the label to visable=false  and on save set the text value if required and change visible =true ?

Answer (score 0):

On form load, do something like this:

```
TheValidMessageLabel.Visible = Page.IsValid;
```

You are probably just setting the visible state to true when it's valid and never setting it to false again.

Answer (score 0):

Set your success label visibility in page load to false.
And only if operation is successfully set that label visibility to true.

cheers